# Update field using dictionary and list

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor, dictionary

I have two layers, layer A and layer B. I need to update the SC field on layerA from layerB SC_1 field. I have the following that does a spatial join, then use a Distinct list to populate the SC_1 field. When I run the following nothing happened, no error. The SC field on layer A is blank/empty and the SC_1 from layer B may have blank/ empty attributes as well. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, is it because I have blanks/ empty attributes?

If layerB(memory\sjpoints) SC_1 = Portland, I need layerA SC field to be populated with "Oregon",
if layerB(memory\sjpoints) SC_1 = Anchorage, I need layerA SC field to be populated withAlaska,
etc.

```
import sys, os, arcpy
import arcpy

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
map = aprx.listMaps()[0]
lyr = map.listLayers("layerA")[0]
lyt = aprx.listLayouts()[0]
mf = lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT")[0]

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\layer.gdb"   

lyra = "layerA"
lyrb = "layerB"

SC = "SC"
SC_1 = 'SC_1' 

sjpoints = "memory\sjpoints"

arcpy.SpatialJoin_analysis(lyra, lyrb, sjpoints)
search_feats ={f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sjpoints,SC_1)}
print(search_feats)

place_dict = {"Memphis": "Tennessee", "Anchorage": "Alaska", "Portland": "Oregon", "Los Angeles": "California", "Seattle": "Wasington"}
#print(place_dict)

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(lyra, SC) as upd_cur:
    for upd_row in upd_cur:
        print (str(upd_row))
        upd_row[0] = place_dict.get(upd_row[0], upd_row[0])
        print (str(upd_row))
        upd_cur.updateRow(upd_row)
```

Comment: what do you see when you print `search_feats`? Add that to your question, also try setting `place_dict.get(upd_row[0], upd_row[0])` to `place_dict.get(upd_row[0])` because if upd_row[0] does not exist how can you set it to it?

Comment: With a selected feature the "search_feats" prints {'Portland'}.

Comment: The layer (lyra) is most likely to have a blank record in the SC field.

Comment: Looking at your code it occurred to me you do a spatial join create a set called `search_feats` and then do absolutely nothing with it.  May be you should put a blank entry into you `place_dict` so the lookup captures that scenario?

Comment: Correct, I guess that is issue. I am not sure how to do that. The SC field for the selected feature will always be a bank or null. I need to update that selected features SC to the state name based on the city.

Comment: That's the root of your problem if the value in the field SC is always null then it has no match in your place_dict. You need to rethink how you are using your spatial join output.

Comment: ok, any ideas, suggestions, examples?